# Does Spring Security require a custom login controller when providing a custom login form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Does [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) [4.0.1.RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE) require a custom login controller when providing a custom JSP page containing a login form composed of two input fields, user name and password?  Spring Security sample application [`spring-security-samples-chat-jc`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/chat-jc) has a very simple one, but [`spring-security-samples-form-jc`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/4.0.1.RELEASE/samples/form-jc) doesn't define one at all.

Comment: What type of custom login form are you talking about? Generally, a login form would consist of userName & password which Spring security is well designed to take care of. Please elaborate on the question.

Comment: i don't think so, I think you just need to POST the request to a right url with the right params

Answer (score 0):

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter has the method named configure and inside it you can do something like this:

```
http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password");
```

After this you do not need to create a controller. Just POST to /login endpoint with urlencodedparameters named as email and password.

Comment: Why do you disable [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)?

Comment: What is the difference between methods `loginPage()` and `loginProcessingUrl()`?

Comment: loginProcessingUrl() is address to POST. loginPage() is address of the login form. I disabled it because i use spring-boot as REST server for mobile application.

Comment: So your application does not have a login JSP page?

Comment: Why does the example in the [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) documentation section [Java Configuration and Form Login](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form) specify method `loginPage()`, but not `loginProcessingUrl()`?

Comment: Yes you're right, I do not have a login page. All the things work as REST services. It does not specify because it explains the form login with a login page.